# What is the parameter which is varied when running sklearn.metrics.plot_roc_curve on a SVM?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am confused by this example here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/visualizations.html

If we plot the ROC curve for a Logistic Regression Classifier the ROC curve is parametrized by the threshold parameter. But a usual SVM spits out binary values instead of probabilities.
Consequently there should not be a threshold which can be varied to obtain an ROC curve.

But which parameter is then varied in the example above?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/65763063/10495893

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVMs have a measure of confidence in their predictions using the distance from the separating hyperplane (before the kernel, if you're not doing a linear SVM).  These are obviously not probabilities, but they do rank-order the data points, and so you can get an ROC curve.  In `sklearn`, this is done via the `decision_function` method.  (You can also set `probability=True` in the `SVC` to calibrate the decision function values into probability estimates.)

See [this section](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#mathematical-formulation) of the User Guide for some of the details on the decision function.